# How to refresh permission after getting access to it

Tags: ios, swift, permissions

I need to access users Photos, for this I ask for permission. There are possible outcomes :

1. Permission granted : In this condition application resumes it normal functioning.
2. Permission Denied : In this case application shows an alert wherein user has option to goToSettings or to just ignore it. If user selects goToSettings and provides access to photos and comes back to application then it still says that permission is not granted. Permissions are only refreshed when I restart my application.

**My Question:** How to refresh the application's permission settings without restarting my application. Similar problem to my question is posted [here.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19433)

**Edit:**

My application is a navigation controller based application and I check for access in my controller's `viewDidLoad`. I just tried if request permissions are refreshed if I pop and push the controller again. No luck, the results where same - it still said permission denied.

**Edit 2 :** Code to check for permissions

```
func requestAccess() -> Void {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization {
        status  in
        switch(status) {
        case .notDetermined, .denied :
           // perform relavent action
            break

        case .authorized , .restricted :
             // perform relavent action
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What setting do you change in iOS settings? If go to Privacy -> Photos -> YourApp and change value, on iOS 10 app is restarted by iOS automatically

Comment: @pilot34  In settings I give application access to Photos. I am not clear on what you mean by in iOS 10 app restarts automatically.

Comment: I tried it in ios 10.2 and 9.3 same result.

Comment: iOS kills your app when you changed privacy settings. And after next tap on app's icon your app is started from scratch. application:didFinishLaunching is called. How do you check permissions?

Comment: try my sample https://monosnap.com/file/nUzXO7rwW48LmcgbddFHYGECGX8mZo

Comment: I have attached the code on how I am asking for permissions. Also I have updated your code which shows what I am trying to achieve. You can check it [here](http://take.ms/DEMac)

Comment: In the app you attached everything works for me:
- open app first time, press cancel in your alert, press "Ask" button and deny access in system alert.
- then open settings from your alert, allow access to photos
- when you switch back to Test app there is "authorized" in label, because app was restarted and permissions were refreshed

Comment: When you change permissions in Settings, iOS kills your app and after restart there are right permissions

Comment: @pilot34 how are you switching back to iOS app ? because when I switch back I still se unauthorized.

Comment: @Prial press "home" button and run "Test" or double tap on home button and run test... Tried on a device and on a simulator

Comment: I was running it in simulator while debugging it with the code which caused the problem. When I just complied the code with made the build the issue don't come. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS kills your app when you changed privacy settings. And after next tap on app's icon your app is started from scratch. application:didFinishLaunching is called and so on. So you don't need to update permissions.

Comment: can any one please share the apple developer's link which specifies that app must kill after changing the permission, so i can show this to client to prove that its default apple's functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate you could have logic in `applicationDidBecomeActive` to re-query the permission store for your updated permissions.

In your viewDidLoad for the view you check permissions on you could observe the notification like so;

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(yourClass.applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)),
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil)
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't Work.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is Objective-C.

I think you can do this when user tapping a button or something:

```
PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];


if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        // ask for authorization
        [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization...

} else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // continue accessing photos

} else {
        // access denied, go to settings if you want

}
```

Comment: I know I can get the status with this code, but thats not problem. Please read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: @Priyal I can tell you definitely it doesn't need a refresh. After changing settings and back to you app, photos will be accessible. So I think something else goes wrong.

Comment: I am able to get the status, when request access popup is shown. What I am trying to do is if user declines for permission then I am showing an alert to ask for enabling the access via settings. It has an action button through which user can be redirected to settings. When user gives access to application through that then it also when user comes back to application it is not being reflected. It only reflects when I restart the application.